# Conditional Formatting in R-Map Points based on Column Value

Tags: r, maps

I'm making a map in R for a project of DC's metro stations. 
[here's the graph I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDXW4.png)

The data came from this code:

```
qmplot(lon, lat, data = metrodata, colour = I('red'), size = I(3), darken = .3)
```

If you need more of the code, please let me know

The points are based on the data from a sheet that looks like this:

```
Name                Line            Lattitude   Longtitude
Anacostia           Green           38.862181   -76.995218
Arlington Cemetery  Blue            38.883282   -77.066677
Bethesda            Red             38.984395   -77.095844
```

is there a way to make the data points for the station be green for the green line stations, blue for the blue line stations and so on?

This is less important but I thought I'd still ask...is there a way to have a custom image as a plot point? (There are some stations with multiple colors...i was thinking of making an image of a circle with half red and half green for Fort Totten, for example.

thank you!